# Nginx Reverse Proxy on Docker - How to connect to other application?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) running in a docker container on my NAS using docker compose. Now I want to setup a reverse proxy in order to make it accessible via my personal domain.

The `joplin/docker-compose.yml` file looks as follows:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:13.1
        volumes:
            - /local/joplin:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - APP_PORT=22300
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=********
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_DB=database
    app:
        image: joplin/server:2.2.10
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - "22300:22300"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - APP_PORT=22300
            - APP_BASE_URL=http://192.168.1.2:22300/
            - DB_CLIENT=pg
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=********
            - POSTGRES_DATABASE=database
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
            - POSTGRES_HOST=db
```

The `nginx/docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    nginx: 
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - /local/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - /local/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

I used the default for my `/local/nginx/nginx.conf`. It is as follows. :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Furthermore, inside the `/local/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder I created the following files:

- `/local/nginx/sites-enabled/example.org`,
- `/local/nginx/sites-enabled/my.example.org`.

The content of `/local/nginx/sites-enabled/example.org` is:

```
##
# example.org -- Configuration
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.org;
}
```

The content of `/local/nginx/sites-enabled/my.example.org` is:

```
##
# my.example.org -- Configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.example.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:22300/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

I set up portforwarding on my router to the nginx container and it works. (I see the 404 screen of nginx when I go to http://example.org) However, I struggle to set up the reverse proxy for the joplin container. When I try to access http://my.example.org, I get a 510 error message. What am I doing wrong?

The weird thing is, when I replace http://192.168.1.2:22300/ with the ip of my personal pc running a test webpage, I can access it via http://my.example.org. Even when I setup Joplin on my pc it works. Something seems to be wrong with either my nginx or docker setup.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of debugging and googling around I finally found the solution. What one has to do is the following:

1. Setup nginx with a network inside `nginx/docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    nginx: 
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - /local/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - /local/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
#----------------------------------------
# Setup network my_net
#----------------------------------------
        networks:
            - my_net
networks:
    my_net:
        driver: bridge
```

2. Make Joplin use the network defined for nginx, and add an extra one for communication to the database. (Plus, setup a name for the Joplin container.)

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:13.1
        #----------------------------------------
        # Setup communication to Joplin server
        #----------------------------------------
        container_name: database
        networks:
            - joplin_net
        #----------------------------------------
        volumes:
            - /local/joplin:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - APP_PORT=22300
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=********
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_DB=database
    app:
        image: joplin/server:2.2.10
        #----------------------------------------
        # Setup communication to Postgres server
        # and nginx
        #----------------------------------------
        container_name: joplin # This will be the name used by nginx.
        networks:
            - joplin_net
            - nginx_my_net
        #----------------------------------------
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - "22300:22300"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - APP_PORT=22300
            - APP_BASE_URL=http://192.168.1.2:22300/
            - DB_CLIENT=pg
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=********
            - POSTGRES_DATABASE=database
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
            - POSTGRES_HOST=db
#----------------------------------------
# You can replace joplin_net with any
# name you like. However, the name for
# nginx_my_net has to be:
#     app folder + '_' + network name
# The nginx application is in the nginx
# folder, therefore the prefix has to be
# 'nginx_'. The network name is 'my_net',
# so this has to be the suffix.
#----------------------------------------
networks:
    joplin_net:
        driver: bridge
    nginx_my_net:
        external: true
```

3. The `/local/nginx/sites-enabled/my.example.org` file has to be amended:

```
##
# my.example.org -- Configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.example.org;
    # The next line make nginx use the docker DNS
    # to find the Joplin container by its name
    # ('joplin').
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30;

    location / {
        # The server name used here has to be the
        # one defined using 'container_name' in the
        # docker-compose.yml for the application we
        # want to proxy to.
        proxy_pass http://joplin:22300/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Hope this saves someone a couple of days of head-scratching.